# How to correct the connection factory error in GeoServer when connecting to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql

I'm trying to set up a connection for PostGIS (external) from my local GeoServer, but when I click Save there occurs the poolable connection factory error.

> Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.1xx.xxx", user "postgres", database "bda_data", no encryption)

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: can you see your PostGIS server from the GeoServer machine?

Comment: no i just type the ip address of the PostGIS server

Comment: in the host page

Comment: It is a violation of best practice to connect  from any application as the admin user. Doing so can result in destruction of your database. Best practice is to create and use a non-owner user for connection with the *least privileges* necessary to make the app work.

Comment: Which means I cant connect geoserver to PostGIS of another system?

Comment: No, it means you must configure the PG instance correctly to connect from another system.

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer needs to be able to open a connection to the remote postgis server. You need to make sure that there is an entry in the `pg_hba.conf` file in the same way as for any other program. You should check with `psql` to make sure things are correctly set up.

As Vince notes you also should not use the super user account  `postgres` for the connection as this gives too much power to an attacker if they break in to your GeoServer machine.

Comment: i edited the pg_hba.conf file with the geoserver's system ip address still there is no hope

Comment: did you restart postgres?

Comment: i disconnected the server and tried again

Comment: i have to disconnect the firewall for both the systems right?

Comment: You would certainly need to open ports in the firewalls - this is now off topic

Comment: Woah, so should I have to open a new port in firewall?

Comment: Even if you do stop the firewall (which you absolutely should **not** do), that still will not correctly configure PostgreSQL to listen on other than localhost. As Ian indicated, you need to correctly configure the pg_hba.conf (or the RDS console equivalent thereof), which is outside the scope of GIS SE. Once you can connect from `psql` on the GeoServer host, if you're still having problems, Edit the Question and vote to reopen.